# is it possible to change the color of a specific window button in electron.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I wanted to remove the default windows top bar and keep only the minimize, maximize and close buttons and i was able to do this with the below config values.

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, "./src/assets/images/favicon.ico"),
    maximizable: false,
    titleBarStyle: "hidden",
    titleBarOverlay: {
      color: "#FFF",
      symbolColor: "#999",
      height: 30
    }
  })
```

but here the problem is that the disabled button is also getting the color #999, but i want it to be a different color to indicate that the button is disabled which was happening when i added only `maximizable: false` propery but it seems like this was overriden by the titleOverlay property.

Is there a way to do this ? other than replacing the default icons with custom icons.

This is what i tried

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, "./src/assets/images/favicon.ico"),
    maximizable: false,
    titleBarStyle: "hidden",
    titleBarOverlay: {
      color: "#FFF",
      symbolColor: "#999",
      height: 30
    }
  })
```

and i was expecting the electron.js would automatically apply a lighter color to maximize button since it is disabled but it didn't.